# Svelte/Sapper - Running __sapper__/build cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, svelte, sapper

I don't get any errors in dev or in the process of actually building via `npm run build`, but upon trying to run `node __sapper__/build` on my linux VM I get a `Cannot find module` error

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/bookbot/htdocs$ node __sapper__/build
Starting server on port 3000
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
    throw err;
    ^Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/groupby'

Require stack:
- /opt/bitnami/apps/bookbot/htdocs/__sapper__/build/server/bookings-b0b7de1b.js
- /opt/bitnami/apps/bookbot/htdocs/__sapper__/build/server/server.js
- /opt/bitnami/apps/bookbot/htdocs/__sapper__/build/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apps/bookbot/htdocs/__sapper__/build/server/bookings-b0b7de1b.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:777:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/opt/bitnami/apps/bookbot/htdocs/__sapper__/build/server/bookings-b0b7de1b.js',
    '/opt/bitnami/apps/bookbot/htdocs/__sapper__/build/server/server.js',
    '/opt/bitnami/apps/bookbot/htdocs/__sapper__/build/index.js'
  ]}
```

I've tried `npm i lodash --save`, makes no difference. Not sure where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `lodash/groupBy` with an uppercase 'B'? How do you make that pass in dev?

Comment: On most operating systems, it's case insensitive, so it makes sense that it would work locally but fail on Linux

Comment: After doing some Googling I imagine this is the correct answer, thanks @rixo. I'll test it tonight and mark the answer. Surprised that MacOS ignores case when resolving modules!